# quay security scanning fails with clair in my container setup

Tags: docker, self-hosting, quay.io, clair

I have a running quay registry and I am able to push images into it. But for some unknown reason, the configured Clair scanning fails.

I don't know if this is a problem with my quay configuration or with my Clair... or with both?
I am grateful for any help and advice. :)

What I expect:
A running Clair scan and display the result :)

What I get:
The Scan is in "Queued" and nothing happens
[image: queued message instead of scan result]

The following error message occurred in quay logs:

```
securityworker stdout | 2024-01-15 22:06:12,770 [284] [ERROR] [util.secscan.v4.api] Security scanner endpoint responded with non-200 HTTP status code: 500
securityworker stdout | NoneType: None
securityworker stdout | 2024-01-15 22:06:12,770 [284] [ERROR] [data.secscan_model.secscan_v4_model] Failed to perform indexing, security scanner API error
securityworker stdout | Traceback (most recent call last):
securityworker stdout |   File "/quay-registry/util/secscan/v4/api.py", line 252, in index
securityworker stdout |     resp = self._perform(actions["Index"](body))
securityworker stdout |   File "/quay-registry/util/secscan/v4/api.py", line 360, in _perform
securityworker stdout |     raise Non200ResponseException(resp)
securityworker stdout | util.secscan.v4.api.Non200ResponseException
securityworker stdout | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
securityworker stdout | Traceback (most recent call last):
securityworker stdout |   File "/quay-registry/data/secscan_model/secscan_v4_model.py", line 417, in _index
securityworker stdout |     (report, state) = self._secscan_api.index(manifest, layers)
securityworker stdout |   File "/quay-registry/util/secscan/v4/api.py", line 256, in index
securityworker stdout |     raise APIRequestFailure(ex)
securityworker stdout | util.secscan.v4.api.APIRequestFailure
```

And a corresponding error message in Clair

```
9:54PM WRN layers fetch failure error="encountered error while fetching a layer: fetcher: request failed: Get \"http://example.com/v2/server/test/blobs/sha256:cc067951b11fb09519e7620e2a9a0e84e216c660aed7a38f4f3cf004354e24e1\": dial tcp 82.165.69.92:443: i/o timeout" component=internal/indexer/controller/Controller.Index manifest=sha256:a98415716a91066ef5e442969887ebb3df7d80775b5bfa7b67fcaed989833d84 state=FetchLayers
9:54PM INF layers fetch done component=internal/indexer/controller/Controller.Index manifest=sha256:a98415716a91066ef5e442969887ebb3df7d80775b5bfa7b67fcaed989833d84 state=FetchLayers
9:54PM ERR error during scan error="failed to fetch layers: encountered error while fetching a layer: fetcher: request failed: Get \"http://example.com/v2/server/test/blobs/sha256:cc067951b11fb09519e7620e2a9a0e84e216c660aed7a38f4f3cf004354e24e1\": dial tcp 82.165.69.92:443: i/o timeout" component=internal/indexer/controller/Controller.Index manifest=sha256:a98415716a91066ef5e442969887ebb3df7d80775b5bfa7b67fcaed989833d84 state=FetchLayers
```

My Setup is with traefik, but I think this is not the main issue because communication seems to work.
My Compose file is:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  quay:
    container_name: quay
    image: quay.io/projectquay/quay:3.10.1
    volumes:
      - ./config/quay:/quay-registry/conf/stack
      # - ./data/quay/registry:/datastorage/registry
    environment:
      QUAY_VERSION:  3.10.1
      QUAY_HOTRELOAD: "true"
      DEBUGLOG: "false"
      IGNORE_VALIDATION: "true"
      QUAYRUN: /tmp
      WORKER_COUNT_UNSUPPORTED_MINIMUM: "1"
      WORKER_COUNT: "1"
    depends_on:
      quay-db:
        condition: service_healthy
      quay-redis:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - quay-backend
      - traefik-servicenet
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.quay.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.quay.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.quay.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.quay.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.quay.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-servicenet"

  quay-db:
    container_name: quay-db
    image: docker.io/library/postgres:15
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "quay"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "quay"
      POSTGRES_DB: "quay"
    volumes:
      - "./config/postgres/pg_bootstrap.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/pg_bootstrap.sql"
      - "./data/quay-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - quay-backend
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U quay -d quay"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 9s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s

  quay-redis:
    container_name: quay-redis
    image: docker.io/library/redis:7
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 60s
    networks:
      - quay-backend

  clair:
    container_name: quay-clair
    image: quay.io/projectquay/clair:4.4.0
    volumes:
      - "./config/clair:/src/clair/"
    environment:
      CLAIR_CONF: "/src/clair/config.yaml"
      CLAIR_MODE: "combo"
    cpus: 2
    command:
      ["bash", "-c", "cd /src/clair/cmd/clair; go run -mod vendor ."]
    depends_on:
      clair-db:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - quay-backend

  clair-db:
    container_name: clair-db
    image: docker.io/library/postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
      - ./config/postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - ./data/clair-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD-SHELL
        - "pg_isready -U postgres"
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 4s
      retries: 12
      start_period: 10s
    networks:
      - quay-backend


networks:
  traefik-servicenet:
    external: true
  quay-backend:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true
```

The quay config.yaml related to clair

```
...
# clair
SECURITY_SCANNER_INDEXING_INTERVAL: 30
SECURITY_SCANNER_V4_ENDPOINT: http://quay-clair:6000
SECURITY_SCANNER_V4_PSK: some_base64==
...
```

And at last my clair config.yaml

```
---
log_level: debug-color
introspection_addr: ""
http_listen_addr: ":6000"
updaters: {}
indexer:
  connstring: "host=clair-db port=5432 user=clair dbname=indexer sslmode=disable"
  scanlock_retry: 10
  layer_scan_concurrency: 5
  migrations: true
matcher:
  connstring: "host=clair-db port=5432 user=clair dbname=matcher sslmode=disable"
  max_conn_pool: 100
  migrations: true
notifier:
  connstring: "host=clair-db port=5432 user=clair dbname=notifier sslmode=disable"
  indexer_addr: http://localhost:6000/
  matcher_addr: http://localhost:6000/
  migrations: true
  delivery_interval: 5s
  poll_interval: 15s
  webhook:
    target: "http://localhost:6000/secscan/notification"
    callback: "http://localhost:6000/notifier/api/v1/notification"
metrics:
  name: "prometheus"

# ===== AUTH
auth:   
  psk: 
    key: 'some_base64=='
    iss:
      - 'quay'
```

Full quay config.yaml:

```
ACTION_LOG_ARCHIVE_LOCATION: default
ALLOWED_OCI_ARTIFACT_TYPES:
    application/vnd.oci.image.config.v1+json:
        - application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+zstd
    application/vnd.sylabs.sif.config.v1+json:
        - application/vnd.sylabs.sif.layer.v1+tar
AUTHENTICATION_TYPE: Database
AVATAR_KIND: local
BUILDLOGS_REDIS:
    host: quay-redis
    port: 6379
CONTACT_INFO:
    - mailto:mail@example.com
DATABASE_SECRET_KEY: 7e597f39-lala-lala-lala-9bfdcee1a628
DB_CONNECTION_ARGS: {}
DB_URI: postgresql://quay:quay@quay-db/quay
DEFAULT_TAG_EXPIRATION: 2w
DISTRIBUTED_STORAGE_CONFIG:
    default:
        - LocalStorage
        - storage_path: /datastorage/registry
DISTRIBUTED_STORAGE_DEFAULT_LOCATIONS: []
DISTRIBUTED_STORAGE_PREFERENCE:
    - default
EXTERNAL_TLS_TERMINATION: true
FEATURE_ACI_CONVERSION: false
FEATURE_ACTION_LOG_ROTATION: false
FEATURE_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS: true
FEATURE_APP_REGISTRY: true
FEATURE_APP_SPECIFIC_TOKENS: false
FEATURE_BITBUCKET_BUILD: false
FEATURE_BLACKLISTED_EMAILS: false
FEATURE_BUILD_SUPPORT: false
FEATURE_CHANGE_TAG_EXPIRATION: true
FEATURE_DIRECT_LOGIN: true
FEATURE_EXTENDED_REPOSITORY_NAMES: true
FEATURE_FIPS: false
FEATURE_GITHUB_BUILD: false
FEATURE_GITHUB_LOGIN: false
FEATURE_GITLAB_BUILD: false
FEATURE_GOOGLE_LOGIN: false
FEATURE_INVITE_ONLY_USER_CREATION: false
FEATURE_MAILING: false
FEATURE_NONSUPERUSER_TEAM_SYNCING_SETUP: false
FEATURE_PARTIAL_USER_AUTOCOMPLETE: false
FEATURE_PROXY_STORAGE: false
FEATURE_REPO_MIRROR: false
FEATURE_REQUIRE_ENCRYPTED_BASIC_AUTH: false
FEATURE_REQUIRE_TEAM_INVITE: true
FEATURE_RESTRICTED_V1_PUSH: true
# clair
FEATURE_SECURITY_NOTIFICATIONS: false
FEATURE_SECURITY_SCANNER: true
FEATURE_STORAGE_REPLICATION: false
FEATURE_TEAM_SYNCING: false
# user
FEATURE_USER_CREATION: false
FEATURE_USER_INITIALIZE: false
FEATURE_USER_LAST_ACCESSED: true
FEATURE_USER_LOG_ACCESS: false
FEATURE_USER_METADATA: false
FEATURE_USER_RENAME: false
FEATURE_USERNAME_CONFIRMATION: false
#
FRESH_LOGIN_TIMEOUT: 10m
GITHUB_LOGIN_CONFIG: {}
GITHUB_TRIGGER_CONFIG: {}
GITLAB_TRIGGER_KIND: {}
LDAP_ALLOW_INSECURE_FALLBACK: false
LDAP_EMAIL_ATTR: mail
LDAP_UID_ATTR: uid
LDAP_URI: ldap://localhost
LOG_ARCHIVE_LOCATION: default
LOGS_MODEL: database
LOGS_MODEL_CONFIG: {}
MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER: support@quay.io
MAIL_PASSWORD: somesecurepassword
MAIL_PORT: 465
MAIL_SERVER: smtp.some.com
MAIL_USE_AUTH: true
MAIL_USE_TLS: true
MAIL_USERNAME: admin@example.com
PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME: https
REGISTRY_TITLE: Project Quay
REGISTRY_TITLE_SHORT: Quay
REPO_MIRROR_INTERVAL: 30
REPO_MIRROR_TLS_VERIFY: true
SEARCH_MAX_RESULT_PAGE_COUNT: 10
SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE: 10
SECRET_KEY: 6cf643d5-lala-lala-lala-a8bdf9a6d341
# clair
SECURITY_SCANNER_INDEXING_INTERVAL: 30
SECURITY_SCANNER_V4_ENDPOINT: http://quay-clair:6000
SECURITY_SCANNER_V4_PSK: some_base64==
# 
SERVER_HOSTNAME: example.com
SETUP_COMPLETE: true
SUPER_USERS:
    - admin
TAG_EXPIRATION_OPTIONS:
    - 0s
    - 1d
    - 1w
    - 2w
    - 4w
TEAM_RESYNC_STALE_TIME: 30m
TESTING: false
USE_CDN: false
USER_EVENTS_REDIS:
    host: quay-redis
    port: 6379
USER_RECOVERY_TOKEN_LIFETIME: 30m
USERFILES_LOCATION: default
```